# The IDE can't open library dependency dialog (Maven dependency)

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

After upgrade Android Studio to 1.2.1.1 Or later , The IDE can't open library dependency dialog (Maven dependency)

it gives this error :

```
Could not initialize class com.android.tools.idea.structure.gradle.MavenDependencyLookupDialog
```

is it a bug ,, or some thing Wrong ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I Found it Finally , in new versions of android studio

you should activate the Maven box from :

new SDK Manager >> Plugins >> Maven Integration >> check this box

Comment: where is that located?

Comment: in android studio  top bar

Comment: @HafizhHerdi What does it do?

Comment: After I checked that box now my IDE working properly

Answer (score 6):

I used @Maher Answer and tried to show graphically

Step 1: In android studio Open **Tools** > **Android** > **Sdk Manager**

[image]

Step 2: Now click or **Plugin** > **Maven Integration** and mark **checked**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Naveed! I have liked your post. What does checking this do anyway? Thanks

Comment: @Rich it is about maven integration, developers add libraries through maven, so in new update developer faced the problem that default maven was not enabled, they have to enable it through this process.